# WordPress Pagination with ajax - Dots

Tags: ajax, pagination, paginate-links

I am using `paginate_links()` along with pagination. It works whenever a number is clicked but if I click 3 dots stays there so no 4 pages can't be selected. Is there any workaround?

[image]

Comment: You will need to return up-to-date pagination controls in your AJAX response. FWIW this is why AJAX sites typically don't use numbered pagination.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use "**mid_size**" to manage number of pages to display in **paginate_links()** function.
Please check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/ for pagination options.
Please see example below to use **mid_size**.

```
$args = array( 
    'mid_size' => 3, 
    'prev_next' => true, 
    'prev_text' => '« Previous', 
    'next_text' => 'Next »', 
); 

$result = paginate_links($args);
```